# GMSK Big error in demodulation MatLAB Simulink

Tags: matlab, modulation, gmsk

I am trying to do a PLC simulation system, but my problem is in GMSK demodulator, in my simulation in Simulink MatLAB my output signal is very different from the input signal, below the model:

[image]

Below the block parameters:

[image]

I start doing this simulation yesterday, the values of each block is the default, and even without de AWGN block the error still appears. Someone knows what is happening?

Comment: i have encount the same things,has the problem been found?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26821)

Answer (score 1):

That’s is because of the delay in the GMSK demodulator. MATLab GMSK demodulator uses Virtebi algorithm. You should delay the Rx BER in order to get back the correct data alignment.